# How to remove second slash URL and change parameter

Tags: php, url, redirect, strtok, lang

please help me to fix this.

I have result url like this

```
mypath/index/id
```

And I want to remove "/id" and change to "/en"

I created this for removing

```
$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$dis_url=trim(strtok($url, '/'));
```

And I created link like this

```
if (isset($_SESSION['lang']) && $_SESSION['lang'] == 'en') {}
    echo " <a href='$dis_url-en'></a>";
if (isset($_SESSION['lang']) && $_SESSION['lang'] == 'id') {}
    echo "<a href='$dis_url-id'></a>";
```

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str_replace()`:

```
$a='mypath/index/id';
echo str_replace("/id", "/en",$a); //result:mypath/index/en
```